# AWS lambda could not connect to EC2 Mysql Server

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have been trying to connect `EC2 mysql server` from `AWS Lambda` which is not happening. I find `Lambda function` is perfectly working when I just comment database fetching code. I am using `Django framework` and  using `zappa` to deploy code to Lambda and add setting in `AWS API GateWay`.

Things I did:

1. Created a user in `Mysql` with the aws `Lambda` host address
2. While deploying with `zappa` Added `Subnet Id` and `Security Group Id` in settings file.
3. Did not create new `VPC` as the `EC2` instance has default `VPC` created. So I just used it.
4. I see it `Lambda function` is working really fine when I just comment Database code(EC2 Mysql database, trying to fetch results from aws lambda).

Code:

```
class GetData(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item_id = request.data.get('item_id')
        if item_id not in [None, '', ' ']:

                item = Item.objects.get(item_id=item_id) # Comment 1
                item_name = item.item_name #  Comment 2

                return Response({"return": "OK OK OK OK"})
        else:
            return Response({"return": "ITEM NOT OK "})
    else:
        return Response({"return": "NOT OK "})
```

In the above code If I just comment out comment 1 and comment 2 lines I am receiving `status code 200` and returning below response

```
{"return": "OK OK OK OK"}
```

Which tells Lambda function is working fine but If I do not comment those two lines I am getting below error

```
Sun Aug 06 13:48:33 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response

Sun Aug 06 13:48:33 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 502
```

I observed above error in `API gateway`. I don't understand where I am going wrong. Help me to debug this issue

**EDIT:**

EC2 security group details:

Inbound:

`HTTP (80) (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0)`, `HTTPS(443) (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0)`, `MYSQL/Aurora(3306)(0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0)`, `SSH(22)(0.0.0.0/0)`

Outbound:

`All trafic`

**EDIT2:**

Cloud watch logs:

```
START RequestId: 29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb Version: $LATEST
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.154Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing BmpImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.170Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing BufrStubImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.170Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing CurImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.171Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing DcxImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.184Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing DdsImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.185Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing EpsImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.187Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing FitsStubImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.188Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing FliImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.189Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing FpxImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.206Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing FtexImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.206Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing GbrImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.207Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing GifImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.211Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing GribStubImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.212Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing Hdf5StubImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.212Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing IcnsImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.227Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing IcoImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.229Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing ImImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.230Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing ImtImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.231Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing IptcImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.244Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing JpegImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.272Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing Jpeg2KImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.272Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing McIdasImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.272Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing MicImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.273Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing MpegImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.273Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing MpoImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.275Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing MspImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.276Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PalmImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.286Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PcdImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.286Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PcxImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.286Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PdfImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.288Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PixarImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.288Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PngImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.288Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PpmImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.289Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing PsdImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.290Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing SgiImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.291Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing SpiderImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.293Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing SunImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.293Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing TgaImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.294Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing TiffImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.294Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing WebPImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.295Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing WmfImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.296Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing XbmImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.305Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing XpmImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.306Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Importing XVThumbImagePlugin
[DEBUG] 2017-08-06T14:40:17.469Z    29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb    Zappa Event: {u'body': u'{\n\t\n\t"item_id" : "345488692474"\n}', u'resource': u'/{proxy+}', u'requestContext': {u'resourceId': u'z2csqk', u'apiId': u'crmb4ybwrk', u'resourcePath': u'/{proxy+}', u'httpMethod': u'POST', u'requestId': u'test-invoke-request', u'path': u'/{proxy+}', u'accountId': u'xxxxxxxxx', u'identity': {u'apiKey': u'test-invoke-api-key', u'userArn': u'arn:aws:iam::6315xxxxxxx:root', u'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, u'accessKey': u'ASIAxxxxxxxLR4UYLYXEQ', u'caller': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'userAgent': u'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_112)', u'user': u'6xxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, u'cognitoIdentityId': None, u'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, u'sourceIp': u'test-invoke-source-ip', u'accountId': u'xxxxxxxxx9'}, u'stage': u'test-invoke-stage'}, u'queryStringParameters': None, u'httpMethod': u'POST', u'pathParameters': None, u'headers': {u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, u'stageVariables': None, u'path': u'/', u'isBase64Encoded': False}
 END RequestId: 29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb
 REPORT RequestId: 29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb Duration: 20003.70 ms   Billed Duration: 20000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB  Max Memory Used: 63 MB  
 2017-08-06T14:40:37.000Z 29f0907a-7ab5-11e7-8f0c-6586a26797eb Task timed out after 20.00 seconds
```

Comment: Please provide the details of the security group assigned to the EC2 instance. Also please provide the CloudWatch logs for the Lambda function which should include the actual error message.

Comment: Added Securty group of EC2 details. Let me add Cloud watch details also..

Comment: What are the source values for the EC2 security group rules? Please provide **ALL** details.

Comment: > **Created a user in Mysql with the aws Lambda host address.**

Are you running the lambda in a configuration that would allow only one IP address to be used? This would be a non-standard implementation and you'd need to go out of your way a bit to do this. Have you tried creating the same `user@%` and seeing if you can connect?

Most commonly I create @% users in RDS and allow the security group to filter traffic correctly.

Comment: Yes I missed the part about using *"the aws Lambda host address"*. How would you even obtain the Lambda host address ahead of time?

Comment: If RDS was publicly facing, and the lambda was internalized in a VPC, rather than using generic public IP addresses, you could put it into a NAT'd subnet with a known external. You could also try to create a subnet with only one available IP... not even sure if that is possible, but certainly is not advisable to try.

Comment: Actually I did not create a user account in Mysql first, just deployed django shown error saying XX.XX.XX.XX is not allowed to connect to mysql as it does not have account MYSQL. so I found  that IP @MarkB

Comment: The IP of the Lambda function will change constantly. You need to create a MySQL account for the Lambda function that doesn't restrict by IP.

Comment: Added Cloudwatch logs.  How to create Mysql Account for Lambda? point me to the link please @MarkB

Comment: @Naroju Luke Waite gave you what you need to create the MySQL account for Lambda. Instead of creating the account with a specific host/ip just use `%`

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. I changed Mysql Account to allow any ip address but still showing the same error.

Comment: I dont know. What happened it isworking now. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

Add a try/except in your handler and log any error, that may help you address this issue. When using Lambda proxy integration, any exception that is not handled will result in a Bad Gateway(502) response.